# Disable or enable code by preprocessor

Tags: ocaml, preprocessor

In C++ I'd write

```
bool positive (int a)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    cout << "Checking the number " << a << "\n";
#endif
    return a > 0;
}
```

In OCaml I could write

```
let positive x = 
    begin
        printf "Checking the number %d\n" x;
        x > 0
    end
```

But how can I disable the printf statement when not in debug mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use cppo : https://github.com/mjambon/cppo.
This is available via opam, and offers C like preprocessor features.

Answer (score 4):

Without preprocessing you can simply have a global flag defined as `let debug = true` and write:

```
if debug then
  printf ...;
```

This code is removed by ocamlopt if `debug` is false. That said, it's cumbersome and should be used only where performance of the production code is critical.

Another, less optimized, option is to have a mutable flag. This is more convenient as you don't have to rebuild the program to activate or deactivate debug logging. You would use a command-line option to control this (see the documentation for the `Arg` module).

```
let debug = ref false

...

if !debug (* i.e. debug's value is true *) then
  printf ...;
```